# How to Create a CURD Application in Angularjs with Codeigniter..?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter-3

if any body know then please help me to create a curd application in Angularjs with Codeigniter.or please suggest me some help full links.

Answer (score 0):

See this link [angular-CRUD](http://github.com/whip8466/angular-CRUD), This is simple demo for beginner. You have to use it with a Codeigniter.

Comment: I think database in missing in project  file.in angular-CURD

Comment: in this demo no need database. if you want to store data then you can create it. it just simple one page angular demo.

Comment: install it and run demo. if it is helpful to you then go through code you get everything. just you have to store it in db. thats it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This Project made in CodeIgniter framework and Angularjs and Kendo UI.
https://github.com/joseazr1987/Angular-CodeIgniter-Zend-Laravel/tree/master/CodeIgniter

Comment: Brother i setup in localhost then its create a problem:-                              `A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 257